# Xamarin Android class library

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

In VS 2015 Community (update 3, version 14.0.25431.01) I made Xamarin Android solution from Android blank template (Xamarin version is 4.3.0.795), and then added Android class library. When app is debugged on phone directly, 2 icons are shown: one has a name which is set in manifest file and that starts the app; and another has name of Android project inside solution. When latter is started, empty view is opened, it only has title on top. Former starts the app. Same happens when apk is published. It should create only one icon. Please help.

Comment: Check in your code  - MainLauncher = true, It should be one thing

Comment: Friend, at first I did not understand your answer. This morning I have done the same mistake in another solution: MainActivity was made from template, I did not use it and it was also marked as main launcher. Thank you so much!

Comment: My English is not perfect ). I'm glad it works.I will write my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your code:

```
 MainLauncher = true
```

It can only be once. If this is twice in your code - then you have two icons.